# Using Jquery to shift reorder list item

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit stumped. I have an unordered list with 5 items. The 3rd item is styled to appear larger than the others.

When clicking on an item, I would like that item to animate into the middle position (like a carousel), and for the remaining list items to shift up or down accordingly.

[image]

```
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li class="bigOne">three</li>
   <li>four</li>
   <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

So if I clicked on the fifth item - the list would become:

```
<ul>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
   <li class="bigOne">five</li>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

And if clicking on the 2nd item the list would become:

```
<ul>
   <li>five</li>
   <li>one</li>
   <li class="bigOne">two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

I've been able to shift the item into the third position - however, I can't quite figure out how to shift all the other items up and animate them into position. I've spent hours messing about with various bits of code over the weekend - but cant get it working.

Here is a link to JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cadud/

As you can see - I'm getting a weird bunching at the start 1, 1 and no class is added to the middle (3rd) element.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hi Arulmr, as I've been playing about with it, I've ended up making a big incoherent mess. Will clean it up and post. Thanks

Comment: Please add your code, so can have more closer look. Try this I think you are asking this: http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel/

Comment: Hi Justnajm and arulmr - js fiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/cadud/  thanks :)

Comment: I have seen the code you are inventing a wheel which is already available. Try using the available demo http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel

Comment: Hi Justnajm,

Tinycarousel doesn't allow me to move by clicking on the element. It also wont move the clicked item to the nth position either. Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is jquery plugin [Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/)  demo

and sourcecode is available at [github](https://github.com/fredhq/roundabout/zipball/v2.4.2)

Comment: Hi Shafqat,
Thanks - I had a play with Roundabout as it nearly does what I want - However, I couldn't get it to show everything in a straight line. It would only allow me to click on the items next to the middle items - and not those elements further away.

Comment: Hi Rob, .roundabout("animateToChild", childPosition)
.roundabout("animateToChild", childPosition, callback)
.roundabout("animateToChild", childPosition, duration, easing)
.roundabout("animateToChild", childPosition, duration, easing, callback). this function will help you to move to particular child. have a look at [API](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/#/api)

Comment: Hi Shafqat - Thanks - have had a play, its very close to what I'm trying to achieve, so will accept this answer. Cheers :) Rob

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a re-arranging of list items with animation. The requirement was that I have five elements:

```
1   2   3   4   5
```

and rearrange order like, when click on 1st element it place the position in center like this:

```
5   4   1   2  3
```

you can check my fiddle: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozLqk4tr/4/)

```js
$('.horizontal li').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var tparent = $(this).parent();
    var childs = tparent.children().length;
    var eachWidth = this.clientWidth + 10;
    var middle = eachWidth * (parseInt(childs / 2));
    var rowChild = $(this).parent().children('li');
    var currentIndex = rowChild.index($(this));

    rowChild.each(function (li) {
        if ($(this).attr("POS")) {
            cp = $(this).attr("POS");
        } else {
            $(this).attr("POS", li);
        }
    });

    function animateEach() {
        rowChild.each(function (li) {
            var _minePos = $(this).position().left;
            var cp = $(this).attr("POS");
            var _newPos = cp * eachWidth;

            $(this).animate({
                left: (cp - li) * eachWidth,
            }, 40, function () {
                // checkPOS();
            });
        });
        setTimeout(checkPOS(true), 40);
    }

    var currentelement = $(this);
    var currentIIN = $(this).attr("POS");

    function checkPOS(ee) {
        if (currentIIN != 2) {
            rowChild.each(function (li) {
                var eachPOS = $(this).attr("POS");
                if (eachPOS >= 4) {
                    $(this).attr("POS", 0);
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("POS", parseInt(eachPOS) + 1);
                }
            });
            currentIIN = currentelement.attr("POS");
            animateEach();
        } else {
            if (ee) currentelement.addClass('active');

        }
    }

    checkPOS();
```

```css
p {
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
ul.horizontal {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
}
ul.horizontal li {
    float: left;
    /*background: #ccc;*/
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.ul.horizontal .li.a {
    border:2px solid #fb7d1e;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.horizontal li.active {
    /*background:silver;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
    /*width:150px;*/
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /*border:1px solid ;*/
    /*border-radius: 1em;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
}
/*background: #ccc;*/
 display: block;
 margin-left: 10px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;

}
.ul.horizontal .li.a {
    border:2px solid #fb7d1e;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.horizontal li.active {
    /*background:silver;*/
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blueviolet;
    font-size: 20px;
    /*height: 150px;*/
    /*width:150px;*/
    webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    /*border:1px solid ;*/
    /*border-radius: 1em;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
    box-shadow: 0 58px 36px -56px #7ac9ff;
}
```

Check my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozLqk4tr/4/)